# Can i have live image of 10 different xp system in one external harddisk

Tags: windows-xp

Actually My issue is  , I am having 10 different system . each is having **xp** installed.

Now for backup, i want to make a live image of each system in my hard disk.so that

when recover required i can recover or can run any system from that external hard disk

Please provide suggestion , how can i achieve that?

System : cp service pack 3 installed
External hard disk : wd: 2TB

Comment: Obligatory: [*Why are you still running Windows XP*](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help)? [Professionals](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) generally don't deploy out-of-support software...

Answer (score 1):

Recovery is easy - just use a disk imaging tool with a live medium and recover the backup file to the system.

Running the system of the backup disk will be more difficult, but you **really** don't want to do this anyway - this is a backup medium, not meant for running live.

Also: Windows XP as in the product out of support?

Comment: I know that xp is out but i just want to know can i have backup of 10 different system in one harddisk? what would be the best software to do that.

Comment: We don't do product recommendations. See the [help].

Comment: ok leave the software name but can u tell me if i can achieve my objective.

Comment: As I said, it's easy. Any linux live system has rudimentary tools for this (think `dd`), and specialized [disk imaging software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disc_image_software) will offer much more.